# push new git branch to remote repo on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I can't find the answer anywhere...
I created a local branch from my master branch on my local repo.

Now, I want to push my branch to bitbucket (my master branch is already syncing fine)

How can I do that? (I don't have EGit, I can't download it for some reason)

Comment: how do you plan on doing this in eclipse without using egit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Git Bash do :

git push origin "your-name-of-branch"

This command push your origin (local branch) into remote "your-name-of-branch". If "your-name-of-branch" doesn't exist, create it

Comment: You could add the -u option, this will add the upstream tracking reference into the git config file for you:  
i.e. `git push -u origin my_branch`